# How to fix this interference between jumping and dash?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm having a problem developing player mechanics for a 2D platform game. The problem involves the player's jump action and dash action. In the jump, I'm applying a force of 0 on X and 175 on y, making the RigidBody "jump" when the player presses Z. When the player presses C, the game calls a Coroutine that will apply a force of 3 on the X vector and force 0 on the Y vector, throwing the RigidBody forward and performing the dash. The two actions work perfectly, individually. However, if I press Z and C at exactly the same time, the character is thrown diagonally into the air. Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private Rigidbody2D playerRb;
    private float h, v;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public bool attackingState;
    public float speed;
    public float jumpForce;
    public bool leftDirection;
    public int idAnimation;
    public bool Grounded;

    // dash system variables
    public bool canDash = true;
    private bool isDashing;
    private float dashPower = 3f;
    private float dashingTime = 0.2f;
    private float dashCoolDown = 0.8f;

    void Start()
    {
        canDash = true;
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (isDashing)
        {
            return;
        };

        if (h > 0 && leftDirection == true && attackingState == false && canDash == true)
        {
            flip();
        }
        else if(h < 0 && leftDirection == false & attackingState == false && canDash == true)
        {
            flip();
        };

        if(v < 0)
        {
            idAnimation = 2;
            if(Grounded == true || canDash == false)
            {
                h = 0;
            }
        }else if(h != 0)
        {
            idAnimation = 1;
        }else
        {
            idAnimation = 0;
        };

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X) && v >= 0 && attackingState == false)
        {
            playerAnimator.SetTrigger("atack");
        };

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) && v >= 0 && Grounded == true)
        {
            //playerRb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            playerRb.AddForce(new Vector2 (0, jumpForce));
        };

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) && canDash == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
        };

        if(attackingState == true && Grounded == true)
        {
            h = 0;
        };

        playerAnimator.SetBool("Grounded", Grounded);
        playerAnimator.SetInteger("idAnimation", idAnimation);
        playerAnimator.SetFloat("speedY", playerRb.velocity.y);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isDashing)
        {
            return;
        }

        Grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.02f);
        playerRb.velocity = new Vector2 (h * speed, playerRb.velocity.y);
    }

    void flip()
    {
        leftDirection = !leftDirection;
        float x = transform.localScale.x;
        x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(x, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
    }
    public void atk(int atk)
    {
        switch(atk)
        {
            case 0:
                attackingState = false;
                break;

            case 1:
                attackingState = true; 
                break;
        };
    }

    IEnumerator Dash()
    {
        canDash = false;
        isDashing = true;
        float originalGravity = playerRb.gravityScale;
        playerRb.gravityScale = 0f;
        //playerRb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        playerAnimator.SetTrigger("dash");
        playerRb.velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x * dashPower, 0f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingTime);
        playerRb.gravityScale = originalGravity;
        isDashing = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashCoolDown);
        canDash = true;
    }
}
```

I've been guided by some people to use return; when to call jump and dash. But I don't know exactly how to apply it.

Another person guided me to make the vector value 0 using Vector2.zero before executing the jump and before executing the dash, I did that but it didn't work either. (The locations of these lines of code are now commented out in the script).

My goal is to make sure the vectors don't add up so the player doesn't get thrown in the air diagonally.

Comment: it happens because  in your code you allow for both to happen. You have used return elsewhere.  Id say do the same for dash/jump as it is the only action you want to perform. OR you can use else ifs so if one is satisfied the rest dont get done

Answer (score 0):

As @BugFinder says in the comment, don't allow both to happen, put an else in between.

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X) && v >= 0 && !attackingState)
{
    playerAnimator.SetTrigger("atack");
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) && v >= 0 && Grounded)
{
    playerRb.AddForce(new Vector2 (0, jumpForce));
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) && canDash)
{
    StartCoroutine(Dash());
};
```

Also a boolean variable is an expression in itself, so don't compare it to true or false. Put a ! in front to negate it.
I made it so that you cannot attack, jump or dash at the same time.